# Graph: Prove that $\chi(G)+\chi(G^c)\leq n+1$

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ a graph on $n$ vertices. Prove that $$\chi(G)+\chi(G^c)\leq n+1,$$ where $chi$ denote the minimum vertex coloring such that no two adjacent vertex has that same color.

**My proof (which is doesn't work):**

By induction, for $n=0$, there is nothing to prove. Suppose the assumption true. Let $G$ a graph on $n+1$ vertices $\{v_1,...,v_{n+1}\}$ and let $\tilde G=G\backslash \{v_{n+1}\}$. By hypothesis, 
$$\chi(\tilde G)+\chi\big(\tilde G^c\backslash \{v_{n+1}\}\big)\leq n+1.$$

Suppose that $\deg_G v_{n+1}=m\leq n$, then $$\chi(G)= \chi(\tilde G)+m+1.$$ Moreover, $\deg_{G^c}v_{n+1}=n-m$ and thus $$\chi(G^c)=\chi\big(\tilde G^c\backslash \{v_{n+1}\}\big)+n-m.$$

We conclude that 
$$\chi(G)+\chi(G^c)\leq \chi(\tilde G)+\chi\big(\tilde G^c\backslash \{v_{n+1}\}\big)+n+n-m\leq n+1+2n-m=3n+1-n$$

and thus it doesn't work.

**Question :** How can I prove he claim ? (any proof is welcome, but I need an induction proof).

Comment: What does $\chi $ denote?

Comment: I think $\chi $ means the euler-charakteristka.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a universal symbol. $\chi$ denote the minimum vertex coloring such that no two adjacent vertex has that same color.